# Java : How to contnually update a file in a loop

Tags: java

I'm writing a code that needs to continually updates a text file in a loop: remove the actual content and write another one. The problem is the update in not done correctly. It uses the previous version of the file.

For example, in loop 4, the called file is the file updated in the loop 3.

My question is how to update my file correctly ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
for(int level:levels){
            RecipeTree.CloneTree(root,  partialroot);
            for(int i =0; i<100; i++){
                RecipeTree.removalcondition = RecipeTree.levelOfConditions(depth, length, recipe, level);
                System.out.println(removalcondition);
                RecipeTree.PartialTree(partialroot, RecipeTree.removalcondition);
                // Here the update of the file
                InitSTRIPSPlanner(partialroot);
                for(RecipeTree leaf: partialroot.getLeaves()){
                    ...........
                }    
            }   
        }
public static void InitSTRIPSPlanner(RecipeTree root) throws IOException{
        String adresseBut = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/prolog/test-2p/Domain_knowledge.pl";
        String adresseSource = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/prolog/test-2p/STRIPS_planner.pl";
        try {
            copyFileUsingStream(new File(adresseSource), new File(adresseBut));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        File fw = new File (adresseBut);
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(fw,true);
        output.write("\n".getBytes());
        output.flush();
        FromTreeToProlog(root,output);
        output.close();
    }

    public static void FromTreeToProlog(RecipeTree root, OutputStream output) throws IOException{
        for(RecipeTree leaf: root.getLeaves()){
            if (leaf.getHead().getPostconditions() != null) { 
                output.write("\n".getBytes());
                output.flush();
                output.write("\n".getBytes());
                output.flush();
                if (leaf.getHead().getPreconditions() != null) {
                    output.write(("strips_preconditions("
                            + leaf.getHead().getName().toLowerCase() + ",["
                            + leaf.getHead().getPreconditions().toLowerCase()+ "]).").getBytes());
                    output.write("\n".getBytes());
                    output.flush();
                }
                else {
                    output.write(("strips_preconditions("
                            + leaf.getHead().getName().toLowerCase() + ",[_]).").getBytes());
                    output.write("\n".getBytes());
                    output.flush();
                }

                output.write(("strips_achieves("
                        + leaf.getHead().getName().toLowerCase() + ","
                        + leaf.getHead().getPostconditions().toLowerCase()
                        + ").").getBytes());
            }
        }
        for (String i : conditions) {
            output.write(("strips_primitive(" + i.toLowerCase() + ").").getBytes());
            output.write("\n".getBytes());
            output.flush();
        }
        for (String recipe : RecipeTree.RecipeCondition) {
            output.write(("strips_preconditions(" + recipe.toLowerCase() + ",[_]).").getBytes());
            output.write("\n".getBytes());
            output.flush();
            output.write(("strips_achieves(" + recipe.toLowerCase() + ",c"
                    + recipe.toLowerCase() + ").").getBytes());
            output.write("\n".getBytes());
            output.flush();
            output.write(("strips_primitive(c" + recipe.toLowerCase() + ").").getBytes());
            output.write("\n".getBytes());
            output.flush();
        }
    }

    private static void copyFileUsingStream(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(source);
            os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } finally {
            is.close();
            os.close();
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: I think you could come up with a small sample so you can first see if you are doing the process of updating right and second other can help you better.

Comment: I can't see continous file updating in all that prolog tree logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
new FileOutputStream(fw, true);
```

is *appending* and should be either one of

```
new FileOutputStream(fw, false);
new FileOutputStream(fw);
```

if I understand you correctly.

BTW.

```
copyFileUsingStream(new File(adresseSource), new File(adresseBut));
```

could be (since Java 7):

```
Files.copy(Paths.get(adresseSource), Paths.get(adresseBut),
    StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```